# Android Manifest is not working properly

Tags: android, sms, manifest

after some hardcore investigation I decided to ask you for help.
I created app which sends some text messages from SQL database.
I want to use smsManager so message will be sent right away. 
I added manifest permition but when I install app there is not confirmation that user agree with messages and messages are not sent. Do you have some experience with this? I did different app with SMS earlier and same manifest permition worked... Emulator works with that so no errors from logCat:(

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Konfigurační zprávy"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SaveRecord"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_save_record"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".ZobrazeniSeznamu" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DataList"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_data_list"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".SMS"></activity>
</application>
```

Noobish sms manager

```
public class SMS extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvUkazka;
Button bOdeslat;
EditText tvCislo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);

    tvUkazka = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvUkazka);
    tvUkazka.setText(DataList.smsText);

    tvCislo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCislo);

    bOdeslat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bOdeslat);
    bOdeslat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
            String cislo = tvCislo.getText().toString();
            String telo = DataList.smsText;

                //Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + cislo);
                //Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                //smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", telo);
                //startActivity(smsIntent);

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(cislo, null, telo, null, null);
            Intent navrat = new Intent(SMS.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(navrat);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Něco je špatně", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Which version of android are you targeting? Newer versions require you to request permissions.

Comment: It is truly duplicate. Thank you. It is newest version